# Swift UIActivityindicator not appearing when loading a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to use the ActivityIndicator to show the user the website is loading but the ActivityIndicator will never appear.  It is supposed to be spinning while the website is loading and stop and hide when the website is done.  Do I have to connect the indicator to the delage or something. Here is my code all in swift.

```
    //
//  WebsiteViewController.swift
//  ParseStarterProject-Swift
//
//  Created by Lucas on 1/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Parse. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class WebsiteViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var Active: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url  = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
          webView.delegate = self

        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)
  {

    Active.startAnimating()



    }

   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
    {
        Active.stopAnimating()




    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You need to make your view controller the webview delegate http://stackoverflow.com/a/34472607/2303865

Comment: That didnt work I updated the code to what I have now.

Comment: make sure your activity indicator is placed above the uiwebview in your view hierarchy in IB, and make sure the it's color isn't white

Comment: I think it is check my code

Comment: Still nothing when I click it

Comment: @MazzaMan Your website loaded?

Comment: Yes sorry should have refrased that

Comment: If I have the cosole print instead of the activity indicator spinning it works

Comment: @MazzaMan Can you zip or upload your source to somewhere so i can check?

Comment: Here is the link in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wn7wamqdp4ty34h/AADxXGMByvvaUYfzsBZ2Ej1Oa?dl=0

Comment: Your activity indicator is placed below the webview in IB

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate it!